# css slideshow background loading slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

I have made a simple slideshow for my background using css, however, because I'm using keyframe I have no idea how to make all the backgrounds use background-size: cover. I want all of the pictures to fit the screen properly.

Also the pictures take like 2 seconds to load when you first open the website. (it just shows white then you see the picture load)

And finally I also want to to make the website responsize, e.g make the background pictures change size depending on the screen size.

If I use a normal

```
body {

   background-image: url("picture.jpg");

}
```

Then I would use @media, but in this case I have no idea what would work.

Also as you can see I have done quite a bit of the number%, I am trying to make the pictures stay longer on the screen whilst making the animation of rotation quicker.

Here is my css (I know it's a silly way to make a background slideshow but it's the easiest :) )

```
body {
  background-size: cover;
  animation: div 25s infinite;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}


@keyframes div {
  0% {
    background-image: url("4.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  15% {
    background-image: url("4.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  25% {
    background-image: url("3.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  35% {
    background-image: url("3.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  45% {
    background-image: url("1.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  55% {
    background-image: url("1.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  65% {
    background-image: url("5.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  75% {
    background-image: url("5.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  85% {
    background-image: url("4.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    background-image: url("4.jpg");
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Here is the website:

https://student.oedu.se/~sc0007/sak/sida_1/sida_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (its white in the beginning and later the picture gets loaded) often may arises due to high quality picture.
[this link](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-optimize-image-loading-on-your-website-855020fb41ae) might help you with it

You should include the following  viewport element for making it responsive

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

`width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device

`initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.